# Как получить данные из DialogFragment в MainAcivity?

Tags: android

в примере работы с DialogFragment

(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=ru)

есть реализация метода `onDialogPositiveClick`

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
                      implements NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener{
    ...

    public void showNoticeDialog() {
        // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        DialogFragment dialog = new NoticeDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
    }

    // The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
    // Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following methods
    // defined by the NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener interface
    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's negative button
        ...
    }
}
```

NoticeDialogFragment:

```
public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    /* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
     * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
     * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
    public interface NoticeDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    NoticeDialogListener mListener;

    // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the     NoticeDialogListener
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Build the dialog and set up the button click handlers
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null))
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                       mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // Send the negative button event back to the host activity
                       mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
                   }
               });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

на DialogFragment'е размещен `EditText`, требуется получить введенные данные

пробовал так

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

    EditText et = (EditText) dialog.getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Log.d("myLog", et.getText().toString();
}
```

, но получаю ошибку

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

вопрос: как правильно получить данные из DialogFragment ?

Comment: Что-то не видно где вы диалогу свою разметку задаёте. Может там просто и нет EditText?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, поправил код, изначально был исходник из примера. EditText есть, AndroidStudio видит его по ID, ощущение что на момент обращения элемент уже удален. При закрытии диалога элементы не удаляются автоматически?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызывая `getView` на экземпляре DialogFragment-a вы получаете разметку фрагмента, вместо разметки AlertDialog, коий находится во фрагменте. Засим обращайтесь к внутренней разметке так:

```
dialog.getDialog().findViewById(...);
```

---

Либо передавайте значения вместо самого диалога через интерфейс, получив значения ещё в самом дилоге, а не из аргумента интефрфейса в активити [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14829540/3212712):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
builder.setView(dialogView)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            EditText valueView = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText); //here
            if(valueView == null) Log.d("AA", "NULL");
            else{
                String value = valueView.getText().toString();
                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(EditLicenseDialogFragment.this, value);
            }
        })
```

Comment: спасибо, у меня были схожие подозрения

Comment: попробовал передать и `dialogView` через аргумент интерфейса, получилось обращаться и из `MainActivity` к `DialogFragment`. Видимо проблема не в `onDeattach`, а в том что к загружаемой  через `inflater` форме не удается обратиться через `getView`

Comment: @ravend, возможно вы правы. Попробуйте вот так: `dialog.getDialog().findViewById()` или даже так: `dialog.findViewById()`

Comment: спасибо, сработал `dialog.getDialog().findViewById()`

Comment: @ravend, дополнил ответ